# Centralize Claim Configuration for Service Providers WSO2 IS 5.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I recently updated my environment from WSO2 IS 5.0.0 to WSO2 IS 5.2.0. My environment consists of 2 machines that are creating a cluster (using the WKA membership scheme and Load Balancer(AWS ELB) with sticky session enabled). I am using MySQL(not the default H2 database). The machines on which the IS is deployed are Windows Server 2012 R2 (EC2 AWS machines).
I noticed that if I want to return particular set of claims I must:
- Update the Claim Configuration of the particular Service Provider
- Make sure /_system/config/oidc has the necessary claims stored in the "openid" property
- Make sure the claims stated in the Claim Configuration of the Service Provider are populated in the identity profile
Is there a way to centralize the claim mappings and not have to configure the claims for each Service Provider?
I noticed that I could update directly the SP_CLAIM_MAPPING table in the database, but is there another way achieve this result?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to centralize claim mappings in Identity Server. You have to specify claim mappings in each SP separately.

It will be supported in a future release. You can find some discussions [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/architecture@wso2.org/msg12289.html).

Thanks
Isura